# Tomcat prefix to every Spring url with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security

Currently I'm facing issue with redirecting application which is behind proxy server:

To see application I need to go to:

```
http://myserver.net/PREFIX/configuration
```

And I need to add PREFIX to every url which will be returned by spring. Currently after successful logging with spring security when I return

```
.successForwardUrl("/configuration")
```

It's redirecting me to url address which is not existing:

```
http://myserver.net/configuration
```

Is there any possibility to add Tomcat prefix to dispatcher servlet? To make somehow default path for the application:

```
http://myserver.net/PREFIX/
```

I was trying to use:

```
server.servlet.contextPath=PREFIX
```

But problem is that when I use context path, I need to go

```
http://myserver.net/PREFIX/PREFIX/configuration
```

To be redirected properly to spring controller. Maybe there is possibility to set up context path but only for response?

Comment: Have you tried using `.successForwardUrl("configuration")` (without slash) ?

Comment: @mrkernelpanic I just tried, and if I try without slash I receive exception during application startup - 'configuration' is not a valid forward URL

Comment: Can you try `defaultSuccessUrl("/configuration", true)` instead?

Comment: @mrkernelpanic I tried, I receive 404, but I think its more related to dispatchers, because whole application routing should have this prefix, errors, login page, logout page, controllers etc.

Comment: @dur Actually my application is jar package and it is started as a normal jar, its running on the same server on which there is another application (I'm not sure how it looks like, I don't have access to it) which is redirecting traffic to my application which is on localhost:9000, because port 9000 is blocked by firewall.

Comment: @dusiu To make it clear: You are running your application with Spring Boot and embedded Tomcat. What happens if you run your application on your local computer without the other application. Could you access your application with `http://locahost:9000/PREFIX/configuration`?

Comment: @dur On my local machine, I can access everything using link http://localhost:9000/configuration/ and there is no problem. Issue is that, when I want to deploy application on test environment (and all others) I dont have access to application port, so I can't see application on using server ip i.e.: 10.0.0.0.1:9000/configuration, only way to see application is by url http://myserver.net, but it is some application which is redirecting also to other apps we having, http://myserver.net/PREFIX/ is to my application, by http://myserver.net/PREFIX/configuration you can enter to main controller

Comment: @dusiu: Then your problem is not your own application, then the proxy application. What proxy do you use? Apache web server? Zuul? Or...

Comment: @dur Yes, is it Apache server, do you know maybe how to set up, that if I will have context Path in spring, and prefix in Apache, it will not be repeated like /PREFIX/PREFIX/configuration, but /PREFIX/configuration?